# Bootstrap Card image enlargement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, card, bootstrap-cards

I want the pictures in the card to enlarge when clicked. I couldn't do it anyway.
I tried a lot but I couldn't. I can enlarge normal photos with Lightbox. However, when I click on the cards, the picture does not enlarge.
The codes are a bit complicated but I hope you can help.
**HomeController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        if(Settings::find('active_upload')->value == 0){
            toastr()->warning(__('main.new_entries_paused'));
            return redirect('/');
        }
        
        Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'story' => 'required|string|min:'.Settings::find('minimum_characters')->value.'|max:'.Settings::find('maximum_characters')->value,
            'tags' => 'nullable',
            'category_id' => 'required',
            'genders_id' => 'required',
            'age' => 'required',
            'photo' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:2048'
        ],[
            'title.required' => 'Bir Başlık Giriniz.',
            'title.max' => 'Başlık 255 Karakterden Uzun Olamaz.',

            'story.required' => 'Boş bırakılmamalıdır.',
            'story.min' => 'Girilen Metin '.Settings::find('minimum_characters')->value.' Karakterden Fazla Olmalıdır.',
            'story.max' => 'Girilen Metin ' .Settings::find('maximum_characters')->value.' Karakterden Az Olmalıdır.',

            'category_id.required' => 'Kategori Seçmeniz Gerekiyor.',

            'photo.image' => 'Lütfen Resim Dosyası Yükleyiniz.',
            'photo.mimes' => 'Dosya Biçimi jpg,png veya jpeg olmalıdır.',
            
            
        
        ])->validateWithBag('write');
  
        // if word censored is active
        if(Settings::find('words_censored')->value == 1) {
            
            $censor = new CensorWords;
            $badwords = $censor->setDictionary(base_path('/vendor/snipe/banbuilder/src/dict/dictionary.php'));
            $string = $censor->censorString($request->story)['clean'];
            
        } else {

            $string = $request->story;
        
        }
        //
        
        // create item
        $create_item = Items::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'story' => $string,
            'slug' => $this->make_slug($request->title),
            'status' => Settings::find('new_entries')->value,
            'user_id' => Auth::id(),
            'category_id' => $request->category_id,
            'genders_id' => $request->genders_id,
            'age' => $request->age,
        ]);
        
        if ($create_item) {

            // if exists, upload photo
            if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {

                // upload original
                $path = $request->file('photo')->store('photos');

                // store photo
                $storePhoto = Photos::create([
                    'item_id' => $create_item->id,
                    'filename' => $path
                ]);

            }

            // create tags
            $tags = explode(",", $request->tags);
            $create_item->tag($tags);
            
            if(Settings::find('status_points')->value == 1){
                if(Settings::find('status_points_new_entry')->value == 1){
                    Points::create([
                        'user_id' => Auth::id(),
                        'point_type' => "new_entry",
                        'score' => Settings::find('points_new_entry')->value,
                        'item_id' => $create_item->id
                    ]);
                }
            }
            
            if(Settings::find('new_entries')->value == 1){
            
                toastr()->success(__('main.toast_your_post_has_been_posted'));
                return redirect('/');
                
            } else {
                
                toastr()->warning(__('main.toast_post_in_moderation'));
                return redirect('/');
                
            }
            
            
        } else {
            toastr()->error(__('main.toast_there_are_problems_try_again'));
            return redirect('/')->withErrors($validator, 'write')->withInput();
        }
        
    }
```

**Items.php**

```
public function photo()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Photos::class, 'item_id');
    }
```

**item.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="card mb-3 shadow @if($item->featured == 1) card-featured @endif">
        <div class="card-header {{ $item->gender->bg_color }}">
            <div class="col text-truncate">
                <a href="{{ route('show', ['id'=>$item->id, 'slug'=>$item->slug]) }}" class="text-white text-decoration-none">
                    <h3 class="card-title">
                        {{ $item->gender->name }} - {{ __('main.years_old', ['age' => $item->age]) }} - {{ $item->category->name }}
                    </h3>
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-auto">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="card-dropdown text-white" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-filled " width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><circle cx="5" cy="9" r="1" /><circle cx="5" cy="15" r="1" /><circle cx="12" cy="9" r="1" /><circle cx="12" cy="15" r="1" /><circle cx="19" cy="9" r="1" /><circle cx="19" cy="15" r="1" /></svg>
                    </a>

                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::id() == $item->user_id || Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdministrator())
                        <!-- actions enabled by the post user -->
                        <a href="{{ route('delete_user_post', $item->id) }}" onclick="return confirm('Do you confirm this operation?');" class="dropdown-item">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon dropdown-item-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><line x1="4" y1="7" x2="20" y2="7" /><line x1="10" y1="11" x2="10" y2="17" /><line x1="14" y1="11" x2="14" y2="17" /><path d="M5 7l1 12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h8a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2l1 -12" /><path d="M9 7v-3a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h4a1 1 0 0 1 1 1v3" /></svg> 
                            {{ __('main.card_delete') }}
                        </a>
                        <!-- end actions enabled by the post user -->
                        @endif

                        <a href="{{ route('report', $item->id) }}" onclick="return confirm('Do you confirm this operation?');" class="dropdown-item text-warning">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon dropdown-item-icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><line x1="5" y1="5" x2="5" y2="21" /><line x1="19" y1="5" x2="19" y2="14" /><path d="M5 5a5 5 0 0 1 7 0a5 5 0 0 0 7 0" /><path d="M5 14a5 5 0 0 1 7 0a5 5 0 0 0 7 0" /></svg>
                            {{ __('main.card_report') }}
                        </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        @if($item->photo()->exists())
        <div class="card-img-top img-responsive img-responsive-16by9" style="background-image: url({{ asset('storage/app/'.$item->photo->filename) }}); opacity: 0.8;"></div>
      
        @endif

        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title text-truncate text-muted">
                {{ $item->title }}
            </h3>
            
            <p class="h3">
                {{ Str::limit($item->story, $story_preview_chars) }}
            </p>

            <p>
                @foreach($item->tags as $tag)
                <a href="{{ route('tag', ['slug' => $tag->slug]) }}" class="badge bg-azure-lt">
                    {{ $tag->slug }}
                </a>
                @endforeach
            </p>
        </div>



        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="row g-2 mb-2 align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="likePost({{ $item->id }})">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="like-icon-{{ $item->id }}" class="icon @if(Auth::check()) @if(Auth::user()->hasLiked($item)) icon-filled text-danger @else text-muted @endif @else text-muted @endif" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M19.5 13.572l-7.5 7.428l-7.5 -7.428m0 0a5 5 0 1 1 7.5 -6.566a5 5 0 1 1 7.5 6.572" /></svg>
                    </a>
                </div>

                <!-- share -->
                <div class="col-auto">

                    <span class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="text-muted" data-bs-boundary="viewport" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M11 7h-5a2 2 0 0 0 -2 2v9a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h9a2 2 0 0 0 2 -2v-5" /><line x1="10" y1="14" x2="20" y2="4" /><polyline points="15 4 20 4 20 9" /></svg>
                        </a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item text-success strong" href="whatsapp://send?text={{ url('view/'.$item->id.'/'.$item->slug) }}" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon dropdown-item-icon text-success strong" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M3 21l1.65 -3.8a9 9 0 1 1 3.4 2.9l-5.05 .9" /><path d="M9 10a0.5 .5 0 0 0 1 0v-1a0.5 .5 0 0 0 -1 0v1a5 5 0 0 0 5 5h1a0.5 .5 0 0 0 0 -1h-1a0.5 .5 0 0 0 0 1" /></svg>
                                {{ __('Whatsapp') }}
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={{ url('view/'.$item->id.'/'.$item->slug) }}&t={{ $item->title }}" target="_blank">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon dropdown-item-icon text-primary" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M7 10v4h3v7h4v-7h3l1 -4h-4v-2a1 1 0 0 1 1 -1h3v-4h-3a5 5 0 0 0 -5 5v2h-3" /></svg>
                                {{ __('Facebook') }}
                            </a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://twitter.com/share?url={{ url('view/'.$item->id.'/'.$item->slug) }}&text={{ $item->title }}" target="_blank">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon dropdown-item-icon text-info" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M22 4.01c-1 .49 -1.98 .689 -3 .99c-1.121 -1.265 -2.783 -1.335 -4.38 -.737s-2.643 2.06 -2.62 3.737v1c-3.245 .083 -6.135 -1.395 -8 -4c0 0 -4.182 7.433 4 11c-1.872 1.247 -3.739 2.088 -6 2c3.308 1.803 6.913 2.423 10.034 1.517c3.58 -1.04 6.522 -3.723 7.651 -7.742a13.84 13.84 0 0 0 .497 -3.753c-.002 -.249 1.51 -2.772 1.818 -4.013z" /></svg>
                                {{ __('Twitter') }}
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </span>

                </div>
                <!-- end share -->

                <!-- bookmark -->
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="savePost({{ $item->id }})">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="save-icon-{{ $item->id }}" class="icon @if(Auth::check()) @if(Auth::user()->hasFavorited($item)) icon-filled @else text-muted @endif @else text-muted @endif" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"><path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/><path d="M9 4h6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14l-5 -3l-5 3v-14a2 2 0 0 1 2 -2" /></svg>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- end bookmark -->
            </div>

            <div class="row small">

                <div class="col-auto d-flex align-items-center pe-2">
                    <span class="text-muted text-truncate" style="font-size: 14px;"> 
                        <span id="like-{{ $item->id }}">@json($item->likers()->count())</span> {{ __('main.card_likes') }}
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="col d-flex align-items-center pe-2" style="font-size: 14px;">
                    <span class="text-muted text-truncate">
                        {{ $item->itemView() }} {{ __('main.card_views') }}
                    </span>
                </div>

                <div class="col-auto align-items-center" style="font-size: 14px;">
                    <a href="{{ route('show', ['id'=>$item->id, 'slug'=>$item->slug]) }}" class="text-muted text-truncate">
                        {{ __('main.card_comments', ['count' => $item->comments()->count()]) }} <i class="fa-regular fa-comment"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"I want the pictures in the card to enlarge when clicked"* isnt this a client side (javascript) issue?

Comment: A js can be written through the codes I sent

Comment: Looking at your markup it appears that in order to increase the size of the image you will need to increase the the width of the parent `div.col-lg-3` as bootstrap scales it to fit within that width.

Comment: how can i do it with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
@if($item->photo()->exists())
        <a href="{{ asset('storage/app/'.$item->photo->filename) }}" data-lightbox="photos">
        <div class="card-img-top img-responsive img-responsive-16by9" data-lightbox="photos" style="background-image: url({{ asset('storage/app/'.$item->photo->filename) }}); opacity: 0.8;"></div>
        </a>
        @endif
```